# iOS app fails to build on App Center: SQLCipher-prefix.pch not found

Tags: ios, visual-studio-app-center

My iOS app fails to build on App Center giving this error message:

```
error: Build input file cannot be found: 
'/Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Pods/Target Support Files/SQLCipher/
SQLCipher-prefix.pch' 
(in target 'SQLCipher' from project 'Pods')
```

My Podfile looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'MyApp' do
  #use_frameworks!

  pod 'SQLCipher', '~>4.0'
  pod 'AppCenter'

end
```

Locally everything builds fine. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake. `.gitignore` had `*.pch`. It was based on a Visal Studio template.